# rsyslog: "-" prepended to action path / ftp.* does not log

Tags: logging, rsyslog, configuration

following config rules:

```
auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog
#cron.*                         /var/log/cron.log
daemon.*                        -/var/log/daemon.log
ftp.*                           /var/log/vsftpd.log
```

First 2 lines mean, log everything to syslog except auth and authpriv, log them to auth.log.
Cron log is disabled by comment, daemon.* is in both syslog and daemon.log.

**ftp.* logs to syslog but not to vsftpd.log, why?**

**what is the "-" prependet to the path?**

I read the manpages but could not find information 'bout that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ftp` facility will end up being ignored if your platform does not define `LOG_FTP`. This is probably the reason why -- it's interesting to note that `ftp` isn't included as a valid facility in the `rsyslog.conf` manpage, most likely to avoid having to explain it.

```
* Mon Oct 12 18:29:44 CEST 1998: Martin Schulze <joey@infodrom.north.de>
*      Added `ftp' facility which was introduced in glibc version 2.
*      It's #ifdef'ed so won't harm with older libraries.
```

Looking at the source code, you can see where this happens in `runtime/srutils.c`:

```
syslogName_t    syslogFacNames[] = {
    {"auth",         LOG_AUTH},
    {"authpriv",     LOG_AUTHPRIV},
    {"cron",         LOG_CRON},
    {"daemon",       LOG_DAEMON},
    {"kern",         LOG_KERN},
    {"lpr",          LOG_LPR},
    {"mail",         LOG_MAIL},
    {"mark",         LOG_MARK},             /* INTERNAL */
    {"news",         LOG_NEWS},
    {"security",     LOG_AUTH},             /* DEPRECATED */
    {"syslog",       LOG_SYSLOG},
    {"user",         LOG_USER},
    {"uucp",         LOG_UUCP},
#if defined(LOG_FTP)
    {"ftp",          LOG_FTP},
#endif
    {"local0",       LOG_LOCAL0},
    {"local1",       LOG_LOCAL1},
    {"local2",       LOG_LOCAL2},
    {"local3",       LOG_LOCAL3},
    {"local4",       LOG_LOCAL4},
    {"local5",       LOG_LOCAL5},
    {"local6",       LOG_LOCAL6},
    {"local7",       LOG_LOCAL7},
    {NULL,           -1},
};
```

The `-` behavior is a bit nuanced. You'll need three URLs for the complete picture.

- [Documentation of the `-` behavior](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_actions.html) -- Search for "syncing"
- [Note about the default behavior change with syncing in V3](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v3compatibility.html)
- [Documentation of `$ActionFileEnableSync`](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_global.html)

The short version: as of V3, a `-` prefix by itself specifies if you want a file to be **omitted** from disk syncing, but this is only meaningful if syncing has been enabled at all with `$ActionFileEnableSync on`.

It's still useful to include the syntax in your configuration if you operate with a mixed syslog daemon environment and there is a practice of sharing compatible configs between servers.

Comment: Nice explanation, tyvm. I wonder why the facilities ( auth, authpriv, cron, daemon, kern, lpr, mail, mark, news, security (same as auth), syslog, user, uucp and local0 through local7) are so limited?
In vsftpd man it sais "syslog_enable
    If enabled, then any log output which would have gone to /var/log/vsftpd.log goes to the system log instead. Logging is done under the FTPD facility."
Even with ftpd instead of ftp it does not work..

Comment: I think I see what's going on, I've updated my answer. The answer is probably going to end up being your OS.

Comment: How can I test weather LOG_FTP is defined?
Using Debian 6.0.6, rsyslogd 4.6.4

Comment: That should definitely be recent enough to define `LOG_FTP`. Did rsyslog generate a 0 byte FTP log when you restarted the daemon? If so, try the following and see if it gets logged. `logger -p ftp.info test` If that works, you need to reconfigure vsftpd to actually use syslog.